# How to get MySQL query result returned using $.ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, ajax

i'm trying to update is a javascript which when you hover over an image, a div object floats near your mouse with information, this information is stored in a .js file as an array,

eg.

```
Text[0]=["image 1","data 1"]
Text[1]=["image 2","data 2"]
```

in the past if this array is change/data added to/removed from it would require uploading a new copy of the .js file, if data was added to/removed from it would also require a change to the .dwt file for the new image which would update every file that use the .dwt file as the main template which could result in 20+ pages being uploaded

i figured i can automate this by using the database by flagging records if they are active and using a mysql query to get only those which are active, this way a blackened app can add to the database and deactivate record thus eliminating having to upload files every so soften.

to do this, i had planned on storing the information in the database and building the above array based off the results, researching how to use mysql queries in javascript lead me to code like this

```
$.ajax( "path/to/your.php" )
    .done(function() { alert("success"); })
    .fail(function() { alert("error"); })
```

now i understand that i need to make a .php file which runs my query and that my formatting of the query results into the array would be one in the `.done` part but what i don't understand is what i'm supposed to do in the .php file to output the query results how in the `.done` part i'm supposed to reference the output

bellow is the code i use to echo my query results to the page to ensure i am getting results

```
$resultIndex = 0

while($row = $results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    echo '<'.strval($resultIndex).'><br>';
    echo 'id = 'strval($row['id']).'<br>';
    echo 'name = 'strval($row['name']).'<br>';
    echo 'desc = 'strval($row['desc']).'<br>';
    echo 'active = 'strval($row['active']).'<br>';
    echo '-----------------------<br>';
    $resultIndex += 1;
}
```

i am wondering 2 things

1. do i just `echo` or `print_r` what i want returned from my .php file
2. how to i access what my .php file returns in `.done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using http://www.php.net/json_encode to output into Json. Yes, just echo the output. On success, a callback is called passed with the data from server.

```
$.post (url, function (data){
    //do some stuff with data from server
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 1):

Your $.ajax function just points to a page and reads the data on that page. If you want that page to use MySQL, you will need to use php to set up the MySQL query and print the data. The layers of a web app are complicated, but I'll try to break it down for you.

A traditional php/mysql setup works like this:

- Javascript:

  - Client side, only deals with content already available on the page. Often edits html based on user interaction.
- HTML

  - Client side, defines the content on a page
- PHP

  - Server side, runs on the server and construct the html
- MYSQL

  - Server side, used to communicate between the php and the database
- Database

  - Server side, used to permanently store data

Ajax is a way for the Javascript layer to call some php in the background. That php can use MySQL to access data in the database and print it out in a format that the javascript can parse and use. Typically the javascript will then edit the HTML.

Comment: while you answer the first part of my question regarding how to get my .php page to return you don't actually answer the second part about being able to access the data that would be returned, however you provide some good insight into the process